# simpl-schema auto generate _id for subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-collection2, simpl-schema

I have a schema for a subdocument as follows

```
const childSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: () => this.docId,
  },

  name: String,

  members: {
    type: Array,
    optional: true,
  },
  'members.$': String,
})
```

and i am attaching that as a subdocument schema in another schema

```
const ParentSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: () => this.docId,
  },

  name: {
    type: String,
  },

  children: {
    type: Array,
    optional: true,
  },
  'children.$': childSchema,
});

ParentCollection.attachSchema(ParentSchema);
```

i am updating the parent document as follows

```
// name and members prepopulated
const child = {
      name,
      members,
    };

ParentCollection.update(
    { _id: id },
    {
      $push: { children: child },
    }
);
```

My understanding is `_id` in childSchema would be auto generated because of

```
_id: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: () => this.docId,
  },
```

but i get the following error

```
Error: ID is required (children.0._id) in parent update
I20210922-09:37:29.819(-7)?     at getErrorObject (packages/aldeed:collection2/collection2.js:506:17)
I20210922-09:37:29.820(-7)?     at doValidate (packages/aldeed:collection2/collection2.js:478:13)
I20210922-09:37:29.820(-7)?     at Collection.Mongo.Collection.<computed> [as update] (packages/aldeed:collection2/collection2.js:199:14)
```

Comment: what is `docId`?

Comment: the docId is to generate an _id inside the autovalue
ref: https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-collection2#autovalue

Comment: "For an insert, this will be set only when it is provided in the insert doc, or when the operation is initiated on the client." -- I don't think either is true in your case, right?

Comment: yes, after inspecting with the debugger found out that `this.docId` is `undefined`